# Why WebLogic doesn't recognize third party jar

Tags: java, weblogic

I am deploying a war file in WebLogic. The same war files was deployed and ran successfully in Tomcat. But when I tried to run this war file in WebLogic server, third party jar APIs are not being recognized. 
I have searched web and I got the following solution, but still it didn't work.

I added the below code in weblogic.xml file

```
 <container-descriptor>
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
 </container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Please provide more details such as what third party jar files did you use? What did you put these jar files in the war? What error did you see during the runtime when running in WLS.

Comment: did you add this library under WEB-INF\lib or APP-INF\lib or under weblogic Domain?

Comment: and do you use this library on Servlets or EJBs ?